# Dapper array of custom types

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

Using dapper I'm trying to map a column that is an array of custom types but there seems to be no example of this anywhere. Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Data"
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Data_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "Value" real NOT NULL,
    "UDFs" "UDF"[],
    "Timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
```

Note the UDFs column here which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE public."UDF" AS
(
    "Name" text,
    "Value" text
);
```

Now I currently have my model set as such:

```
public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UDF[] UDFs { get; set; }

}
```

And the UDF class:

```
public class UDF 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Dapper.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Error parsing column 2 (UDFs=2 - Single)'
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__124`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
   at backend.Repository.DataRepository.FindAll() in c:\Users\davidk\Desktop\ProjectSaturn\backend\Repository\DataRepository.cs:line 43
   at backend.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in c:\Users\davidk\Desktop\ProjectSaturn\backend\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 26
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
```

I have read that you need to use a custom type mapper but I can't really see any good examples of this. Does anyone know where I would find more info?

Oh the DB I'm using is postgres.

Answer (score 3):

Your UDFs column contains an array?  I don't think Dapper can deal with array values in a single column.  The more typical case would be to have a separate table for UDFs, then join them in the query.

```
public class UDF
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<UDF> UDFs { get; set; }
}

string sql = @"SELECT
        d.Id,
        d.Value,
        d.Timestamp,
        u.name,
        u.value
FROM Data d
INNER JOIN UDFTable u ON d.Id = u.Id";
```

then you can do

```
QueryAsync<Data, UDF, Data>(
        sql,
        (data, udf, data) => {
            data.UDFs.Add(udf);
            return data;
        },
        new { },
        null, true, "Id", null, System.Data.CommandType.Text)
```

Comment: I actually looked into this method and I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. An inner join will return multiple rows if there is multiple UDFs connected to a single Data row. Also you are setting the Key of the UDF to the Key of the Data row which will not allow for a 1 to many relationship between the Data row and the UDF table. The only way would to have a foreign key column on the UDF table but again my problem is I want to return back a single row of data even though their are multiple rows of UDFs attached.

Comment: Right, UDF table would have a foreign key to Data table.  u.ID would be a Data key in my example (not PK of UDF).  Dapper doesn't collapse your dependent lists automatically. So, let's say there is one Data with two UDF.  What you'll end up with is a list of two Data objects, identical except each of them containing one of the 2 UDFs. So you end up having to collapse them as I explained to this poster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463783/how-do-i-map-multiple-lists-with-dapper/45493011#45493011

Comment: Awesome thanks I'll maybe try that Schema later but for the moment I'm just converting it to JSON.